# Instantly copy files from one location to the other

Tags: files, file-copy

I have a situation where there are few autosys jobs monitoring the files and then based on the file availability its triggering the dependent jobs.
What I am looking for: As soon as a file arrives from another system, the file should be copied at one more location, before any other job (autosys or custom code), picks it up for processing.
Is there any UNIX OS file watcher functionality available?

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is...

```
inotifywait -m -r -q -e close_write --format "%w%f" <DIR TO WATCH> 2>&1 | (while `true` ; do read FILE_NAME ; <DO WHATEVER WITH ${FILE_NAME}>; done)
```

However, you may find that that whatever is running is also watching the directory and may operate on the file before the above has a chance to do its thing. You could use it to inject something into your job system though.